# How to use Eclipse Interface Command Provider in Activator class in OSGI

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, osgi-bundle

I'm new to code with Eclipse Interface Command Provider. I saw an example at the website

```
public void _say(CommandInterpreter ci) {
    ci.print("You said:" + ci.nextArgument());
}

@Override
public String getHelp() {
    return "\tsay - repeats what you say\n";
}
```

It is used to get command as String and print it again.

Now this is another one to execute the command

```
String command = intcp.nextArgument();
if (command != null) {
    intcp.execute(command);
}
```

Why we use this `execute(command)` method? and How to use it? Are there any examples for it ?

Comment: The `execute(String)` method runs existing commands, as if user typed it in. It's not particularly useful as you probably want to write your own commands. Maybe explain what are you trying to achieve and what is  causing you problems.

Comment: @Banthar I try to implement a calculator program, Therefore I have to give two numbers as inputs along with the method, How do I use the this `execute` method in it? I want like this: If I want to add to numbers there is a method `_add` then I call it like `add 10 20`. Is it possible? or How do I use it in a different way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OSGI console is used mainly for debugging OSGI applications. It's not very convenient way to implement a calculator. Plain console application would be better. Anyway, it's a good way to familiarize yourself with the API.

First, create a class implementing [CommandProvider](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/osgi/framework/console/CommandProvider.html):

```
public class Calculator implements CommandProvider {

    // add prints sum of its two arguments
    public void _add(CommandInterpreter ci) {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(ci.nextArgument());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(ci.nextArgument());
        ci.println(a+b);
    }

    // quit just calls "exit"
    public void _quit(CommandInterpreter ci) {
        ci.execute("exit");
    }

    @Override
    public String getHelp() {
        return "";
    }

}
```

You need to register it in your bundle's activator:

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

    public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        bundleContext.registerService(CommandProvider.class.getName(),
                new Calculator(), null);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

To actually use those command, you need to start RCP application with `-console` command line argument. If your bundle is loaded lazily, it needs to be started before commands will be available:

```
osgi> start com.example.mybundle
osgi> add 2 2
4
osgi> quit
Really want to stop Equinox? (y/n; default=y)  y
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to offer another (and better IMHO) way to write your own commands. Implementing `CommandProvider` interface is not a very good way because it will work only with Equinox. It's better to do it as described in `RFC 147` (well as far as I know it is not published yet but doesn't matter, the way to implement command provider is already described).

You just need to provide OSGi service with two properties:

- osgi.command.scope
- osgi.command.function

In service class you can write public methods that are invoked via your commands. Here is the simple example:

```
public final class MyCommandProvider {

    public void doAction(String id) {
        System.out.println("id=" + id);
    }

    public void doAnotherAction() {
        System.out.println("Another action");
    }
}
```

Now you can register this service (any way you want, for example using `Declarative Services`) and then you will have two commands you can write in OSGi console: `doAction('some string')` and `doAnotherAction`.

You can read more [here](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fconsole_shell.htm).